# Unable to load the assets in production in rails5

Tags: ruby, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Rails 5 , I have changed the application.html.erb to login.html.erb & make the corresponding changes in assets.rb.
My application works fine in development environment, but when 
I run it in production, the css & js are not loading.
I have executed rails assets:precompile first, but it doesn't works, So is it really needed to have application layout in the rails5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for my question.
To make , it work I have to add 'rails_12_factor' gem in my gemfile.
Basically, rails5 added all its functionality except rails_serve_static_assets which is required in production.rb

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
```

If I don't want to add this , then I have to set the above settings as true to make it work.

Layout with different name is working.